# Python Plotly Scatterplot Lines, Unwanted Connecting

Tags: python, plotly

I have an issue with Plotly which I just can’t seem to figure out. I get the sense that this is an issue that a lot of people might have so hopefully other find this question useful.

I have a plot like this:

[image]

… and I’ve created a log-log model in an external script.

When I add a Scatter trace to the data, I get a bunch of unwanted line connections:

[image]

I'm creating the trace like this:

```
curve = go.Scatter(
    x=sl.population,
    y=sl.fit,
    marker=go.Marker(color='red'),
    name='Fit',
    line=dict(shape='spline')
)
```

Where `sl` is a Pandas DataFrame.

And the scatter points line this:

```
scatter = go.Scatter(                                                        
    x=sl.population,                                                                    
    y=sl.y,                                                                    
    mode='markers',                                                         
    marker=go.Marker(color='#3D3C28'),                                      
    name=ylab,                                                              
    hoverinfo=hoverinfo,                                                    
    text=names,                                                             
)
```

I'm passing these values into a function which I use regularly to create a scatterplots like the ones shown here but with linear trendlines.

So the straightline version of the model works fine, but for some reason I'm having trouble overlaying non-linear curves...

I tried changing the `shape` and `smoothing` args but ended up setting the same results.

So, how do I create a plot like the one below, but with a red line instead of a series of red dots?

[image]